# What word describes a requirement?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I have a requirement, is there such a word which generally describes the actual action or object that meets that requirement?

Examples:

- A student is required to pass the exam with Grade A. In this requirement what is "Grade A"?
- You need a ticket to enter the cinema. What is the "ticket"?

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me of a [prerequisite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prerequisite):

> something that is necessary to an end or to the carrying out of a function

<sub>(source: Merriam Webster)</sub>

That would at least work for the ticket in your example (the ticket is a prerequisite to viewing the movie). It doesn't really work for the grade example; there, it's actually the *passing* that meets the requirement, and passing the exam can be a prerequisite for e.g. another course.

Answer (score 0):

> **requirement** *noun*
>   re·​quire·​ment | \ri-ˈkwī(-ə)r-mənt  \
>   : something required:
>   a : something wanted or needed : NECESSITY
>   production was not sufficient to satisfy military requirements
>   b : something essential to the existence or occurrence of something else : CONDITION
>   failed to meet the school's requirements for graduation
>   <sub>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/requirement</sub>

A student is required to pass the exam with Grade A. In this requirement what is "Grade A"?

> Grade A is a requirement for passing the exam.

You need a ticket to enter the cinema. What is the "ticket"?

> A ticket is a requirement for entry into the cinema.

Comment: If the sentence was "I need to take a fruit to school." - is this whole thing a requirement? A pear or apple meet the requirement, but they themselves must be called something other than a requirement or prerequisite?

Answer (score 0):

requisite [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/requisite)

> as and adj: required; essential.  as a noun: something that is indispensable; a requirement:

As in:

> Algebra is a requisite for taking calculus.